# Wifi stops working every 2 minutes

Tags: networking, 17.10, iwlwifi

guys is recently installed ubuntu 17.1 for the first time
but there is a problem in it the wifi works for few minutes and then stops working then i have to manually turn it off from taskbar and then turn it on again i read all the answers for this question but it still doesn't work.
my network controller is:
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)

if please someone can help me i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my surface pro 2. The problem come from linux-kernel.

To solve the problem, i installed WICD network manager. I don't have problem with wifi disconnected randomly after that.

Take a look at WICD -->  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

if you dont like WICD, you can switch back to the default network manager without any problem.